# help me to resole this error=System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Email: Trigger

Tags: before-trigger

this is my trigger...

```
trigger duplicasyContact on Contact (before insert) {
    if(trigger.isbefore && trigger.isinsert){
        Set<String> str = new Set<String>();
        for(Contact con : trigger.new){
            str.add(con.Email);
        }
        list<Contact> conList = new List<COntact>();
        conList = [select id from Contact where Email =: str];
        list<customer__c> cusList = new List<customer__c>();

        if(conList != null && !conList.isEmpty()){
            for(Contact con : conList){
                customer__c cus = new customer__c();
                cus.customer_email__c = con.email;
                cusList.add(cus);

            }
            insert cusList;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As this is a _before_ insert, requerying (typically not needed anyway) makes no sense.

Comment: Anywho exception is self explanatory,You have to query email field in the SOQL you did.

Comment: Hi shubham badole, you might find useful to visit this link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Change the next line 
`conList = [SELECT id, email FROM Contact WHERE Email =: str];`

Take a look at Pranay's comment

Answer (score -3):

```
trigger duplicasyContact  on Contact  (before insert) {
        list<customer__c> cusList = new List<customer__c>();
        for(Contact con : Trigger.new)
        {   
            if(String.IsNotBlank(con.email)){
                customer__c cus = new customer__c();
                cus.customer_email__c = con.email;
                cusList.add(cus);
            }
        }
        if(cusList.size()>0){
            insert cusList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've downvoted this post because it is a *code dump*. Code dumps tend to be unclear and provoke a lot of back and forth in comments. Please read [answer] and ensure that your answers include a clear explanation of the issue and solution.